# Как на C# “перевернуть” строку: было - 123, стало - 321, не используя массивы?

Tags: c#

Как на C# “перевернуть” строку: было - 123, стало - 321, не используя массивы?

Comment: А для чего хотите использовать ?

Comment: Для развития личного скилла

Comment: Ресурсы: Довольно таки подробная информация о Reverse(), даже исходник дан, тесты, отличия реализаций https://habr.com/ru/post/58333/ http://devnuances.com/c_sharp/reversirovanie-stroki-v-csharp/

Comment: Вот тут много примеров https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string

Comment: `i = 0, j = str2.Length - 1; while (i<j) { str1[i] ^= (str2[j] ^= (str1[i] ^= str2[j])); ++i; --j; }` - с использованием "свапа" методом XOR.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов так тут все равно массив. Идет работа с индексами. По моему автору это не нужно.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Но строка это же и есть массив. Как можно работать с массивом, не используя массив? Брать адреса первого символа первой строки и последнего символа второй строки? Но это уже извращение, имхо. Я это интерпретировал, как "не используя __дополнительные__ массивы".

Comment: @МихаилМуругов не знаю, что автор имел ввиду под "не используя массивы".

Comment: Для развития личного скилла нужно и делать лично, а не спрашивать у других.

Comment: Выводим строку на битмап. Обучаем нейросетку распознавать символы. Переворачиваем изображение. Профит! И скиллы прокачаются по многим направлениям! Хм, но ведь "внутри" нейросетей и битмапов могут использоваться массивы? Эх, такой план провалился...

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.StrReverse(text)` из https://stackoverflow.com/a/8419391/5909792

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var source = "123";
string rez = "";

for (int i = source.Length ; i>0; i--)
{
    rez += source[i];
}
```

PS: всю жизнь как-то почему-то думал что стринг внутри это char[] а оказалось что нет.... https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,65ef2e2156feb071

Comment: ну формально строка **не является** массивом, так что все норм

Comment: не-не-не, массив - это IEnumerable<Char>, но обратное в обшем случае неверно:)

Answer (score 2):

Например, так

```
var source = "123";
var n = int.Parse(source);  
var list = new LinkedList<char>();
while(n > 0){
    list.AddLast((char)('0' + n%10));
    n=n/10;
}
Console.WriteLine(new string(list.ToArray()));
```

как убрать `ToArray()` пока не придумал :)

Comment: Зачем городить огород, когда обычный обход в цикле по символьно решит все вопросы.

Comment: @And это была просто неудачная шутка, я бы мог и так написать `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(string.Empty,"123".Reverse()));` - но мне показалось будет забавно добавить в ответ связанный список, ну и понеслось.

Comment: @tym32167, так через Select какой-нибудь

Comment: @Grundy в смыле?

Comment: я думал был конструктор принимающий IEnumerable :-)

Comment: @Grundy а, не, нет такого, было бы слишком просто )

Comment: Лучше уж тогда с использованием стека сделать. Берем по одному символу и кладем в стек, потом читаем из него и склеиваем :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP изначально делал со стеком, но потом подумал, что стек таки на массиве работает ([его имплеметация](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/stack.cs,30)), то есть как бы не оч по заданию, потому взял связанный список

Comment: @tym32167, формально это детали имплементации так что не должно быть важно :)

Comment: @Grundy ну, да, так то и `string.Join()` [использует](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,175) `StringBuilder`, который [использует](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,56) массивы, просто со стеком это уже совсем очевидно :)

Comment: Ок, вместо стека как структуры данных используем стековый кадр, то бишь рекурсию :) Или ОЗУ это тоже своего рода массив? :D

Comment: @АндрейNOP ага, и на большой строке получим переполнение стека :)